# Restore from external hard drive

Tags: windows, restore

I had to pay to have Windows reinstalled because a you know what deleted my user profiles. In order to restore it myself I created a backup on a external hard drive. How do I restore to the clean version of Windows from the external drive. I'm assuming it would involve DOS commands.

Comment: How did you create the backup exactly? What have you tried already to restore it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. No, we don't know what, but we can try to help you if you provide more details like what is "you know what". Also, you said you had Windows reinstalled and now you want to restore a clean version? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a image backup on the external hard driver?

we can create a whole image backup on the external hard driver, then recover it back if we want.it contains a copy of Windows and copies of your programs, system settings, and files. When you restore your computer from a system image, it's a complete restoration.

we could refer to the following link for detailed steps about create image backup.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/back-up-programs-system-settings-files#1TC=windows-7

then, how to Restore your computer from a system image backup

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/restore-computer-from-system-image-backup

Best regards

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)